# Почему не воспроизводится аудио при нажатии?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, аудио

Механизм работы таков: у каждой нажатой кнопки есть атрибут data-tile. Для примера возьмем data-tile = 3. Когда кнопка нажата в html вставляется sound src="3.mp3" и должен воспроизвестись звук. Но он не воспроизводится, хотя файл по-моему подключен верно. Пример https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-lake-3gcen?file=/package.json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]